# Display dynamic rows with Column using Jsf 2.0 and Primefaces 3.0

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

[image]

I have student records which I need to display as per shown in this image.

I am using Jsf 2.0 and primefaces 3.0 , I am trying by using  but still unable to get correct format.

> My problem is , there is a coulmn with name Exam like FE, SE, TE which
>   comes under single column and there are fixed as there will be only 3
>   examinations.Means for first 3 columns in images need row span 3 as
>   each record will have FE -Math ,SE-Math and TE-Maths and... so on
>   marks for all s3 subjects So how can we make this structure possible
>   like 'for 1 record 3 rowspan' ?

How can we achieve this structure as per shown in this image ?

```
<p:dataTable var="s" value="#{tableBean.studentSummary}">  
    <p:column headerText="ID">  
        <h:outputText value="#{s.ID}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Name">  
        <h:outputText value="#{s.name}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Passing Date">  
        <h:outputText value="#{s.passDate}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Exam">  
        <h:outputText value="#{s.exam}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Maths">  
        <h:outputText value="#{s.math}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Physiscs">  
        <h:outputText value="#{s.phy}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Chemistry">  
        <h:outputText value="#{s.chem}" />  
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableSubTable.jsf maybe?

Comment: Daniel I am also trying by using subtable and also rowsapn and columnspan but unable achieve structure from  Exam column, what should I need to do?

Comment: I haven't worked wit subtables , just thought it might help you a bit...

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. First add rowIndexVar to your p:dataTable tag then render the output conditionally. So your code will look something like this:

```
<p:dataTable rowIndexVar="currRow" value=#{myBean.student} val="s">
  <p:column headerText="Name">  
      <h:outputText value="#{s.name}" rendered="#{currRow lt 1}"/>  
  </p:column>  

  <p:column headerText="Passing Date">  
      <h:outputText value="#{s.passDate}" rendered="#{currRow lt 1}"/>  
  </p:column>  

  <p:column headerText="Exam">  
      <h:outputText value="#{s.exam}" />  
  </p:column> 

  <p:column headerText="Maths">  
      <h:outputText value="#{s.math}" />  
  </p:column>  

  <p:column headerText="Physiscs">  
      <h:outputText value="#{s.phy}" />  
  </p:column>  

  <p:column headerText="Chemistry">  
      <h:outputText value="#{s.chem}" />  
  </p:column> 
</p:dataTable>
```

**UPDATE:** Ok, just realized the error of that approach, but will leave because the rowIndexVar may be useful for someone. Instead modify the rendered attribute to look at the exam field (not positive the syntax is correct):

```
<h:outputText value="#{s.name}" rendered="#{s.exam eq 'fe'}"/>
```